# Ember template not updating when array in model is modified

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a simple array of ints that I'm displaying on a page.

This is my model:

```
var Favorite = Ember.Object.extend({
    stuff: Ember.A([1,2,3,4])
});
```

This is my template:

```
{{#each model.stuff as |num|}}
    <li>{{num}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

In my controller, modifications to this array generally display on the page (such as pushObject()), but modifying elements directly does not cause the page to update.  I have a button on my page linked to this controller action:

```
actions: {
    arrayAdd() {
        this.get('model').stuff[0] = 100;
    }
}
```

Clicking the button modifies the underlying array, but doesn't update the page.  Is there a way to have ember automatically pick up on that change?

I'm doing this in Ember 1.13

Comment: I'm able to work around this by copying the array, making my changes, and doing `model.set('stuff', copy);`    I still feel the array indexer should properly update the value, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the equivalent of `arr[idx] = foo` for an ember array is `arr.replace(idx, 1, [foo])`.

The other thing you could do is to call `this.get('model').notifyPropertyChange('stuff')` after you manually edited the array.

Comment: Thank you!  That is exactly what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

In Ember, you need to use KVO(key value observer) compliant methods so that it will trigger computed property recalculation and observer and update the template. Always we need to use `get` for getting the properties and `set` for setting the values. if you didn't follow ember will throw assertion error sometime.

For array there are KVO methods which is equivalent to standard method.

```
Standard Method ->  Observable Equivalent
pop ->  popObject
push -> pushObject
reverse ->  reverseObjects
shift -> shiftObject
unshift -> unshiftObject
```

In your case, you need to update it like the below, [reference twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/3fe34d63b333f20280336cd22011f678?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

```
arrayAdd() {
        this.get('model.stuff').unshiftObject(100);
    }
```

Note: You can declare array `stuff: [1,2,3,4]` it's good to initialize it in init method.

> I still feel the array indexer should properly update the value,
>   though

Interestingly in glimmer component, you don't need to use getters/setters.

Comment: The problem with this is that the property being notified on is not `myArray`, it's `myArray.[]`. This is fine, except that you cannot nest array observers, so it's not possible to do something like `myObjects.@each.myArray.[]`.  Meaning if you want to edit `myArray`, you need to manually call `notifyPropertyChanged` every time you modify it.  Oof.